# how do i place three div side by side in header

Tags: html

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="header" style="float:left">
<div class="logo">
<img src="some image" height="200px" width="200px"/>
</div>
<div class="name">company name</div>
<div class="pic">
<img src="some image" height="200" width="200"/>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS styling**

```
header{background-color:red;width:1200px;height:400px;float:;}
.logo{width:17%;}
.name{color:#ADFF2F;font-size:48pt;margin-left:250px;width:38%}
.pic{;margin-left:950px;}
```

Comment: If you have more requirements than simple side by side then state them. We don't read minds.

Answer (score 2):

```
.header > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Also, your `header` class in the CSS needs to have a `.` in front of it.

You also need to remove the margin-left from `.pic`

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/DAC7p

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted for this: it directly answers the question. I'd have personally cleared the floats, but your omission of that doesn't warrant a downvote. Whoever did it should've left a comment with their reasons.